# How can I replacing broken DPDT switch with direct wiring?

Tags: switches, dpdt

The "gearbox" of my kids car i broken. It's the kind you sit in (at least the kid) and pushes a button with the foot and the car goes forward or backwards, depending of the state of the "gear". From what I know the "gearbox" is a DPDT switch, it has two positions. As the DPDT switch is broken I need to replace it, but can't i just temporally put it in forward mode only by creating the same bridge between the terminals?

[image]

Here is the simple setup. There is a battery, 12v in the back, a push button for the foot in the front and this switch terminal in the middle. One is double red (+V?) and one is single red. The same for black (Ground?). There is a a double blue and a single white.

If i use a multimeter and check any red/black combination I get +11V so the battery needs charging. Do I bridge double blue with double red or black? Blue with red will maybe make if move forward, and blue and black will make it move backwards? Is that the logic here maybe? Same with the single white with either single red or black? If the double blue is connected to double red, does the single white need to be connected to single black?

EDIT:

I opened up the foot switch and I got even more confused, I found a brown wire:

[image]

I opened up for the two motors and BLUE and BROWN goes to the left motor, BLACK and RED goes to the right motor:

[image]

Sorry for the bad image, the car is red :-)

Comment: You may want to consider adding a [PWM controller](https://youtu.be/unhXEQQk8G8?t=87)...

Answer (score 1):

The blue and white wires seem to be the contacts of the motor and the black and red is the battery.

If you observe the way the black and red wires are connected, you can notice that they are one way in the top connectors and flipped in the lower ones - thus providing the reversing function.

If you connect the middle two prongs to the upper two(individually), the car will move one way (cyan in image). If you, however, connect the middle two prongs to the lower two(again individually), the car will move the other way (magenta in image). 
Naturally, connecting cyan AND magenta at the same time will result in a shorted battery, so don't do that. :)

You should get two wires and jump the connections as indicated in the image. Do make sure the wires make good contact or the contact surfaces might get hot.
[image]

Schematic for the footswitch:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9Sww5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Shorting the motors out when the footswitch is inactive makes the car "apply brakes" (shorting motors out results in them resisting rotation).

Drawing out the schematic also explains the second blue wire in the mode switch.

Comment: Hei Linards! Why do you think about one side has two wires and the other ony has 1?

Comment: Pure speculation, but maybe there are two motors which are connected together with the white wire, but the blue wire is routed seperately for each, or something of the sort. Shouldn't be too much work to just strip the car down so that you can follow the wires, to satisfy your curiosity. :)

Comment: There is two motors, on each of the back wheels

Comment: I added two more images, does it still make sense? Whats the brown one?

Comment: I think at this point you'd do well to actually draw up a schematic of the wires, motors and connectors by continuity checking them, otherwise it's a bit confusing due to the mixed use of colours.

Comment: I drew up the schematic as it did start to make a lot of sense when I thought about it. :)